# Character comparison in C fails

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to parse a Fen String `(char *starting_fen)`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

`starting_fen`: `rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1`

```c
void init_board(char *starting_fen)
{
    int rank = 7, file = 0, fen_length = strlen(starting_fen);

    for (int i = 0; i < fen_length; i++)
    {
        if (starting_fen[i], "/") // <-- works for all characters?
        {
            printf("SYMBOL @ idx %d ==> '%c'\n", i, starting_fen[i]);
            // file = 0;
            // rank--;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my output:

```
SYMBOL @ idx 0 ==> 'r'
SYMBOL @ idx 1 ==> 'n'
SYMBOL @ idx 2 ==> 'b'

//...

SYMBOL @ idx 53 ==> '0'
SYMBOL @ idx 54 ==> ' '
SYMBOL @ idx 55 ==> '1'
```

I tried using `strcmp` (`if (strcmp(starting_fen[i], "/"))`) but got a Segmentation fault...

Comment: `"/"` is string `'/'` is character.

Comment: Use `starting_fen[i]=='/'`. Note the single quotes

Comment: From your program, it looks like `starting_fen[i]` is a `char`. `strcmp` takes two pointers to `char`.

Comment: What do you expect `if (starting_fen[i], "/")` to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer this because it is a funny bug. Here:

```
if (starting_fen[i], "/")
```

You are calling **`,` operator**. So it returns `"/"` which always will be evaluated to `true` (Since it is a address which will have a value not equal to `0`). Your code need to be like this:

```
if (starting_fen[i] == '/')
```

So 2 changes:

1. You need `==` operator to check equality.
2. Characters are identified by `'` not `"`.

Comment: yes thank you. left the ',' in there because I tested `strcmp` just before, the single quotes were the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

This fails:

```
if (starting_fen[i], "/") {
```

because `starting_fen[i], "/"` is always "/" which is not null. See [the wikipdia page about the comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

This fails:

```
if (strcmp(starting_fen[i], "/")) {
```

Because `starting_fen[i]` will be a char, not a pointer to a string. Thus it will try to read a location in early memory and fail.

This fails:

```
if (starting_fen[i] == "/") {
```

Since you are trying to compare a char to a pointer.

This is correct:

```
if (starting_fen[i] == '/') {
```

Comment: "...location in early memory..." ?

Comment: Since OP got a segmentation fault I think it's interpreting the char as a pointer

Comment: `strcmp()` expects both arguments to be null terminated char arrays, argument 1 is not.  Passing an argument of wrong type to a function is undefined.  The resulting behavior will also be undefined.  Since it is undefined, it would be only a guess to state precise reason for the segfault,  But still.  I do not know what _early memory_ means :)  Do you just mean to say memory that is not owned by the process?

Comment: True, in this case the undefined behavior seems to result be reading some invalid memory but there is no guarantee since it's undefined

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself a lot of grief if you use proven standard library functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *starting_fen = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";

    printf( "Given: '%s'\n", starting_fen );

    char *rank[8];
    char *cp = starting_fen;
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof rank/sizeof rank[0]; i++ ) {
        rank[ i ] = cp;
        cp = strpbrk( cp, "/ " ); // standard library function
        *cp++ = '\0';

        printf( "%d '%s'\n", i, rank[ i ] );
    }
    printf( "The rest: '%s'\n", cp );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Given: 'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1'
0 'rnbqkbnr'
1 'pppppppp'
2 '8'
3 '8'
4 '8'
5 '8'
6 'PPPPPPPP'
7 'RNBQKBNR'
The rest: 'w KQkq - 0 1'
```

You may want to start the array index with 7 and count down to 0. That's for you to decide.